# Cross Compile the Kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, volatility

I am trying to achieve something similar to this
https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/wiki/Android#initialize-the-android-build-environment.
Below is the environment I am using:

Ubuntu 14.04, Android Studio 2.3, Android NDK r14, emulator -api22.

I am facing difficulties at step **Cross Compile the Kernel**.
I am targeting the goldfish kernel 3.10 
following are the step I followed. Any help would be really appreciated.

**method 1**:

```
export ARCH=arm
export SUBARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=~/android-ndk/android-ndk-r14/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
```

The tutorial suggesting that we have to run the next command as

```
make goldfish_armv7_defconfig
```

but when I checked the directory "android-source/arch/arm/configs/" there is no such config file there. Some tutorials suggesting that we can just copy and paste the file from kernel 2.6, so I did the same thing, and after that add

```
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULES_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULES_FORCE_UNLOAD=y
```

But futher

```
$ make
```

results in error:

```
arch/arm/mm/mmu.c: In function 'build_mem_type_table':
arch/arm/mm/mmu.c:470:18: error: 'L_PTE_MT_VECTORS' undeclared (first use in this function)
   vecs_pgprot |= L_PTE_MT_VECTORS;
                  ^
arch/arm/mm/mmu.c:470:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
arch/arm/mm/mmu.c: At top level:
arch/arm/mm/mmu.c:637:23: warning: 'early_pte_alloc_and_install' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static pte_t * __init early_pte_alloc_and_install(pmd_t *pmd,
                       ^
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mm/mmu.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/arm/mm] Error
```

**methos 2**:

Everything is same as in method 1, I just changed single variable

```
export ARCH=arm64
```

And run

```
make ranchu_deconfig
```

But I got the same error.

**method 3**:

```
$ export ARCH=arm
$ export SUBARCH=arm
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=~/android-ndk/android-ndk-r14/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
$ make ranchu_defconfig
$ vim .config # added this to .config file

CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULES_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULES_FORCE_UNLOAD=y

$ make
```

This command run successfully: [zImage found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHjUk.png).

But when I run the emulator using the below command

```
root@ubuntu:~/Android/Sdk/tools# ./emulator -avd Nexus5x22 -kernel ~/android-source2/android-source/arch/arm/boot/zImage -show-kernel –verbose
```

I am getting the error of "Linux kernel too old to run ram disk":
    [ram disk error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzT41.png)

Comment: Be sure your `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-` and your `PATH` contains `$HOME/android-ndk/android-ndk-r14/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin`. (This is just first step)

Answer (score 0):

Google's Android Kernel is messed up. They forgot to define `L_PTE_MT_VECTORS` when they back ported this [patch](https://github.com/android/kernel_common/commit/5bc45315d340c0a8272804fcb92c42e952e6b24b).

The solution is to just add it [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b6ccb9803e90c16b212cf4ed62913a7591e79a39/arch/arm/include/asm/pgtable-2level.h#L143).